# In what way can Application.fetch_env!(:myapp, :var) be unsafe?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to understand this warning from credo:

```
Module attribute @types makes use of unsafe Application configuration call Application.fetch_env!/2
```

My module looks like:

```
  @types Application.fetch_env!(:myapp, :record_types) 
  schema "bar" do
    field :type, Ecto.Enum, values: @types, primary_key: true
  end
```

Why is this call considered unsafe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR:* use `Application.compile_env/3` instead.

The module body gets evaluated during compile time. That said, whatever would be set in `runtime.exs` will be discarded upon running.

I am not sure if there was a suggestion to use [`Application.compile_env/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#compile_env/3) after the quoted excerpt from the error message, but the reasoning is the same as with using `Application.get_env/3` during compile time.